# A Compose Key as a Part of a Layout Switch Combination

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb, compose-key, capslock

Why can't I switch my layout with these settings:

```
setxkbmap -layout us,ru -option grp:alt_caps_toggle,compose:caps
```

Is it possible at all to have a compose key assigned on `CapsLock` and a layout switch combination relied on this key?

Also, how to turn off `Shift+CapsLock` combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s have a look at how these things are defined in [xkeyboard-config](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config).

`alt_caps_toggle`:

```
// Pressing Alt+Caps_Lock switches to the next group,
// pressing Caps_Lock toggles CapsLock.
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "alt_caps_toggle" {
    key <CAPS> {
       type="PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
       symbols[Group1] = [ Caps_Lock, ISO_Next_Group ]
    };
};
```

`alt_caps_toggle` maps the caps lock key to `Caps_Lock` (level 1) and `ISO_Next_Group` (level two, accessed by pressing `Alt` (`type="PC_ALT_LEVEL2"`)).

`caps`:

```
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "caps" {
    key <CAPS> { type[Group1]="TWO_LEVEL", [ Multi_key, Multi_key ] };
};
```

`caps` maps both levels to `Multi_key` (compose).

These two definitions are not compatible; they map the caps lock key to different keysyms.  One of them will simply override the other.

You might have to implement this functionality yourself.  You’ll probably want something like this:

```
type="PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
symbols[Group1] = [ Multi_key, ISO_Next_Group ]
```

That is, compose on the first level and group switcher on the second level, with `Alt` as the level 2 switch.